# Assumed Role Cannot Assume Another Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, assume-role

I'm bumping into a role chaining issue when utilizing AWS EKS and I'm not able to identify where the chaining is incorrect.

Role A in account 1 will be assuming role B in account 2.

Role A is an `arn:aws:sts::{ACCOUNT-ID-1}:assumed-role/{ROLE-NAME}/{SESSION-NAME}`

Role B is a standard: `arn:aws:iam::{ACCOUNT-ID-2}:role/{ROLE-NAME}`

Role A is an `assumed-role` because on deployments into EKS, the role is assumed.

The Policy for role A is

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Trust Policy for B is

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "{ORD}"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:sts::{ACCOUNT-ID-1}:assumed-role/{ROLE-NAME}/{SESSION-NAME}"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*The aws:PrincipalOrgID match up correctly on validation

The role assumption is conducted in SpringBoot

```
  @Bean
  public WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider getCredProvider() {
    return WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.builder().roleSessionName("SESSION-NAME").build();
  }

  public AWSCredentialsProvider assumeRole() {
    AWSCredentialsProvider credentials = getCredProvider();
    AWSSecurityTokenService sts = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion("us-west-1")
            .withCredentials(credentials)
            .build();
    return new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder("arn:aws:iam::{ACCOUNT-ID-2}:role/{ROLE-NAME}", "role-b-session")
            .withStsClient(sts)
            .build();
  }
```

This role assumption fails as:

```
com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: 
User: arn:aws:sts::{ACCOUNT-ID-1}:assumed-role/{ROLE-NAME}/{SESSION-NAME}
is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::{ACCOUNT-ID-2}:role/{ROLE-NAME} 
(Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

I am not sure why the above would return an AccessDenied based on the configured trust and permission policies as well as the Java code.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have similar problem

Comment: You might want to ensure that the trust policy in `ACCOUNT-ID-2` is configured to trust access from `ACCOUNT-ID-1`.

Comment: I am also stuck in similar issue, atleast i know the problem in my case.
Problem is the assumed role arn session names will be keep changing on each time the application assumes a role in EKS. so if I add the assumed role arn shown in error message to ROLE-B trust relationship.aws.principal then it works.

in below part
"ArnLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:sts::{ACCOUNT-ID-1}:assumed-role/{ROLE-NAME}/{SESSION-NAME}"
          ]

"{SESSION-NAME}" would be changing and hence it breaks it returns 403.